# Insert query with slash in a varchar field with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string

I have this query in a php variable:

```
insert into `activadosmil` set cod='TAB08-150', stock='5', precio='111.23', categoria='Articulos destacados', subcategoria='PROMOS', descripcion='YARVIK JUNIOR 8" A9 1GB 8GB KIDO'Z ANDRO', ean='8717534019003', canon='111.23', fabricante='YARVIK'
```

And it brokes on descripcion='YARVIK JUNIOR 8" A9 1GB 8GB KIDO'Z ANDRO'

I try to use
 htmlspecialchars($descripcion)

But doesn't work.

How can i replace the ' in php for the code i need to use for mysql??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and `htmlspecialchars()` is about as useful for preventing those as a piece of toilet paper is for soaking up a swimming pool.

Comment: `htmlspecialcharacters` has absolutely nothing to do with SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the proper function to escape special SQL-characters in a string. Depending on which driver you're using, that is [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), [`mysqli::real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or [`PDO::quote`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php).

It is not only ' that needs to be escaped. Using the proper function guarrantees you didn't forget some special character and also handles the character encoding correctly (provided you have set the correct character encoding on the connection using `mysqli::set_charset()` or the corresponding one for mysql or PDO).

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

// The original string
$description = 'YARVIK JUNIOR 8" A9 1GB 8GB KIDO\'Z ANDRO';

// Escape any special characters in the correct way for this database connection
$escaped_description = $mysqli->real_escape_string($description);

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO activadosmil (description)" .
               " VALUES ('$escaped_description');");
```

Answer (score 6):

Escape the characters using a backslash.

```
insert into `activadosmil` set cod='TAB08-150', stock='5', precio='111.23', categoria='Articulos destacados', subcategoria='PROMOS', descripcion='YARVIK JUNIOR 8\" A9 1GB 8GB KIDO\'Z ANDRO', ean='8717534019003', canon='111.23', fabricante='YARVIK'
```

Comment: This only works manually though and is a poor way to solve the problem. You should use something like mysql_real_escape_string($string) or mysqli_real_escape_string($string) to have it automatically escape all instances.

Comment: Work like charm with mysql_real_escape_string function. I was using str_replace($descripcion," \' ", " ' " ) but it wipes all content. Thank you

Comment: Yeah. Moreover, he should consider using **Prepared Statements** with either MySQLi or the PDO extension.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend investigating the prepare feature of the mysqli class as descrbed in the PHP manual page:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php

and also the bind_params feature:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* create a prepared statement */
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);

$query='INSERT INTO activadosmil (cod, stock, precio, subcategoria, ".
"descripcion, ean, canon, fabricante) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)';
if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query));{

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    // NB: the first parameter is a string of single char type indicators
    //      - One for each of the actual parameters s=string, d=double, I=integer, b=blob
    //      - In this case all 8 appear to be string - so 'ssssssss'
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param('ssssssss', $cod, $stock, $precio, $subcategoria, $descripcion, 
                           $ean, $canon, $fabricante);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);


    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Using the bind_param should prevent any problems with quotes.